# Why does Node.js's fs.readFile() return a buffer instead of string?

Tags: javascript, file-io, node.js

I'm trying to read the content of `test.txt`(which is on the same folder of the Javascript source) and display it using this code:

```
var fs = require("fs");

fs.readFile("test.txt", function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data);
});
```

The content of the `test.txt` was created on `nano`:

> Testing Node.js readFile()

And I'm getting this:

```
Nathan-Camposs-MacBook-Pro:node_test Nathan$ node main.js
<Buffer 54 65 73 74 69 6e 67 20 4e 6f 64 65 2e 6a 73 20 72 65 61 64 46 69 6c 65 28 29>
Nathan-Camposs-MacBook-Pro:node_test Nathan$
```

Answer (score 762, accepted):

From [the docs:](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback)

> If no encoding is specified, then the raw buffer is returned.

Which might explain the `<Buffer ...>`. Specify a valid encoding, for example `utf-8`, as your second parameter after the filename. Such as,

```
fs.readFile("test.txt", "utf8", function(err, data) {...});
```

Answer (score 198):

Try:

```js
    fs.readFile("test.txt", "utf8", function(err, data) {...});
```

Basically, you need to specify the encoding.

Answer (score 145):

This comes up high on Google, so I'd like to add some contextual information about the original question (emphasis mine):

> ***Why*** does Node.js' fs.readFile() return a buffer instead of string?

#### Because files aren't always text

Even if *you* as the programmer know it: Node has no idea what's in the file you're trying to read. It could be a text file, but it could just as well be a ZIP archive or a JPG image — Node doesn't know.

#### Because reading text files is tricky

Even if Node *knew* it were to read a text file, it still would have no idea which [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) is used (i.e. how the bytes in the file map to human-readable characters), because the character encoding itself is not stored in the file.

There are ways to [guess](https://www.npmjs.com/package/detect-character-encoding) the character encoding of text files with more or less confidence (that's what text editors do when opening a file), but you usually don't want your code to rely on guesses without your explicit instruction.

#### Buffers to the rescue!

So, because it does not and can not know all these details, Node just reads the file byte for byte, without assuming anything about its contents.

And that's what the returned buffer is: an unopinionated container for the raw bytes in the file. How these bytes should be interpreted is up to you as the developer.

Comment: @Loilo Do `readFile` and `readFileSync` read all the bytes of the file or only the bytes *representing the contents of the file*?

Comment: There was no original question. User @aarosil changed the title to *make* it the question and subsequently render existing answers wrong.

Answer (score 61):

Async:

```
fs.readFile('test.txt', 'utf8', callback);
```

Sync:

```
var content = fs.readFileSync('test.txt', 'utf8');
```

Answer (score 48):

It is returning a Buffer object.

If you want it in a string, you can convert it with `data.toString()`:

```
var fs = require("fs");

fs.readFile("test.txt", function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data.toString());
});
```

Comment: Kind of old, but it should be known that this solution introduces extra overhead since `buffer.toString()` assumes utf-8 encoding anyway. Thus, this would be equivelant to (though, slower than) @hvgotcodes' answer.

Answer (score 22):

The `data` variable contains a `Buffer` object. Convert it into ASCII encoding using the following syntax:

```
data = data.toString('ascii', 0, data.length)
```

Or to `UTF-8` encoding:

```
data = data.toString('utf8', 0, data.length)
```

Asynchronously:

```
fs.readFile('test.txt', 'utf8', function (error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log(data.toString());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the encoding scheme at the second parameter, which is usually be `"utf-8"`. Plain buffer is returned if no coding scheme is mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

It is just a function to return content, to encode that you need to add encoding parameter such as "UTF-8"