# JS read json file and use as an object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, object

I'm trying so get the number of items in the array inside this piece

**JSON**

```
{
  "collection" : [
    {
      "item": "apple"
    },
    {
      "item": "banana"
    }]
}
```

Using the following **JS** *(NodeJS)*:
*Updated with answers from user 'elssar'*

```
var data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(filePath));
console.log(data.collection.length);
```

Expected result: **2**

Without specifying the encoding `data` will be a buffer instead of string (thanks to user nils). JSON.parse should work for both. Now I'm getting an error `Unexpected token ? at Object.parse (native)`. Any idea how to fix this? (using Node 5.2.0)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Node.js' fs.readFile() return a buffer instead of string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456864/why-does-node-js-fs-readfile-return-a-buffer-instead-of-string)

Comment: @nils not really a duplicate, as setting the content type would only give the op a string, which does not solve his problem

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011011/using-node-js-how-do-i-read-a-json-object-into-server-memory

Answer (score 25):

You need to [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) the content of the file to JSON.

```
fs.readFile(filePath, function (error, content) {
    var data = JSON.parse(content);
    console.log(data.collection.length);
});
```

Or

```
var data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(filePath));
```

Alternatively, you could just `require` json files (the file extension needs to be .json)

```
var data = require(filePath);
console.log(data.collection.length);
```

Comment: Your first snippet will probably not work, as `data` is undefined, and even if you used `content`, it would be a buffer.

Comment: @nils oops. fixed :)

Comment: Spotted that as well. Still it doesn't work for me. It still says that `data` is undefined.

The alternative you gave me seems to work. But why is my Intelli saying it IS an built-in function but also states: `use of an implicitly declared global variable 'require'` ??

Comment: You still haven't set an encoding... look at my duplicate link.

Comment: @nils not required. `JSON.parse` works without setting the encoding

Comment: @MatthijsvanHest Just tested the snippet it works. Are your trying to use `data` outside of the fs callback function scope? Since the variable data is local to that scope, it is not available outside. As for your IDEs warning, no clue, don't use it.

Comment: the encoding is not required but does make a difference in returning a buffer or a string.

@elssar , I can;t get it to work. No I'm smart enough to know about scopes, so I'm just using it inside the scope of the fs callback function :).

Comment: Oh, nice to know that JSON.parse works with the buffer as well. Just one thing though, you can't access `data` in the `console.log` outside, because `fs.readFile` is an async call (thus called after all currently running code has finished).

Comment: @nils doh! true, I had forgotten about that. I shall blame the 2 hours of sleep I got last night for this errors :)

Comment: It says `unexpected token ? at Object.parse (native)` using `var data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(filePath));` any idea?

Comment: @MatthijsvanHest what version of node are you using?

Comment: @elssar version 5.2.0

Comment: It could be a problem with your file. While I was testing I can across a file that gave me a similar error

Comment: Try `JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(filePath).toString())`, or `JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf-8'))`