# Why is my fs.readFile returning a buffer instead of XML?

Tags: xml, node.js

I have a function called fetchXML that is suppose to write an XML file to my root directory called feed.xml, and then I want to console.log the data inside feed.xml. I use fs.readFile AND I specify the encoding with 'utf-8' as shown in this question: [Why does Node.js' fs.readFile() return a buffer instead of string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456864/why-does-node-js-fs-readfile-return-a-buffer-instead-of-string)

But still the result of my console.log is a buffer. I checked inside feed.xml and it does indeed contain xml.

```
var out = fs.createWriteStream('./feed.xml');

var fetchXML = function() {
  var feedURL = 'http://www2.jobs2careers.com/feed.php?id=1237-2595&c=1&pass=HeahE0W1ecAkkF0l';
  var stream = request(feedURL).pipe(zlib.createGunzip()).pipe(out);

  stream.on('finish', function() {
    fs.readFile('./feed.xml', 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  });
}

fetchXML();
```

Comment: what node version?

Comment: The latest for experimental features. 7.1

Comment: I assume the err returned from readFile is null?  Also, is the output correct (other than being a buffer instead of a string)?

Comment: There isn't an error, but I'm not sure how to answer your question about whether the buffer is correct or not, I just know it's a buffer instead of a string containing the xml.

Comment: I mean, are the bytes correct ascii for the xml you are expecting?  Also, what zlib library are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The main issue here is that `err` is set in this case and it will tell you that `toString()` failed (due to the size of the file). It then leaves the data it read as a Buffer and passes that as the second argument to the callback.

This could be perceived as a partial bug since most people probably would not expect to see a second argument passed in, but at the same time `err` *is* set (and you should always handle errors) and it *does* give you an opportunity to do something else with the (raw binary) data that was already read into memory.

As far as solutions go, you will probably want a streaming parser for large amounts of data like this (hundreds of megabytes). For XML, one such module that provides a streaming interface is [`node-expat`](https://github.com/astro/node-expat).

Comment: I would like to take the xml and convert it to JSON with xml2js, but when I try that with the "data" it return undefined instead of having JSON. I thought that might have something to do with it returning a buffer.

Comment: You will want to use a streaming parser for very large documents, as I have now noted in my answer.

Comment: What exactly am I trying to accomplish with the streaming parser? I'm a bit confused as to why my current solution isn't working to be honest. I've never done anything like this before, so you'll have to revert to a basic explanation.

Comment: V8 has a max string size and when you ask node to convert the raw binary data to a JavaScript string, it fails because the data is too large. In this particular case the XML data is/was over 300mb and [V8's current max string size](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/ec02b811a8a5c999bab4de312be2d732b7d9d50b/deps/v8/include/v8.h#L2095) is ~268mb. If you use a streaming parser, you can parse the XML chunk by chunk instead of trying to load the entire XML file as one giant string first *and then* parsing it.

Comment: Ok that's makes sense. For node-expat, which function do I need to use? I see a variety of them startElement, endElement etc, but it's not exactly self explanatory how to use them...