# how to consume data from response.write

Tags: javascript

I am opening an html page with the code below.  I am also sending is data to that page with the response.write() function:

```
fs.readFile('./calc.html', function(error, data){
   if(error){
       //do nothing for now              
   } else if (data){
       resp.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
       var sum = 9;
       resp.write(sum);
       resp.end(data);
   }
});
```

How do I consume the value from 'sum' in calc.html when the page opens?  In the script tag in the , I'm utilizing the Window.onload method to perform an action when the page loads.  The number 9 appears in the top left hand corner of the web page when it loads, so I konw it's there, I just dont know how to consume it and use it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var htmlSum = 0;
    function fetchData() {
        htmlSum = //How to I scrape the 'sum' variable sent into the page?????
    }
    window.onload = fetchData;        
</script>
```

Comment: Your code is very far from being usable and doesn't make any sense whatseover.  You've read a file but then not even used the file's content.  You've declared a number and then written it with JSON.stringify.  It's not JSON, it's a number.  Start out with code that is more basic and fits your skill level better.

Comment: I'm just doing a proof of concept.  Lighten up.

Comment: @nikotromus Why don't you write value inside an html element with some specific id and query it afterwards. ie `resp.write(\`<p id="myData">${sum}</p>\`);` and then just query element with with `#myData`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're writing here gets received as an HTML page (in this case), which is why it just displays the number "9" in the browser.  If you package it inside a `<script>` tag it will be available as JS:

```
resp.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
var sum = 9;
resp.write('<script type="text/javascript">var mySumVar = ' + sum + ';</script>');
return resp.end(data); //the "return" doesn't change anything,
                       //but it's good practice to make sure the function ends here
```

...And you can then access `mySumVar` from your other clientside scripts.  Note that this will go in the global scope, which makes it easier to access but also bad practice.  You may want to package it inside some other object to avoid polluting the scope.

Comment: This is the answer that the OP is looking for, but it is indeed pretty bad practice. What OP is looking for is a [templating language in JS](https://www.developerdrive.com/best-javascript-templating-engines/).

Answer (score -2):

Instead of writing the number at the top of the page, you can write placeholders that will be replaced with your data. For example, you could use `{{sum}}` as a placeholder and replace `{{sum}}` with your sum:

```
fs.readFile('./calc.html', function(error, data){
   if(error){
       //do nothing for now              
   } else if (data){
       resp.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
       var sum = 9;
       resp.end(data.replace("{{sum}}", sum);
   }
});
```

and in your html..

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var number = 0;
    function fetchData() {
        number = {{sum}};
    }
    window.onload = fetchData;        
</script>
```

If you are planning to include more logic from the serverside into your webpage, I would recommend you look into a template engine such as [EJS](https://ejs.co/).

Comment: I've get the following:  TypeError: data.replace is not a function

Comment: What does `typeof(data)` return?

Comment: console.log(typeof(data));     -> object

Comment: Try casting `data` to a string before doing the replacement.

Comment: [When no encoding is specified, `readFile` returns a buffer rather than a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6457004/3297291). This solution should work, if you include an argument for the HTML file's encoding.