# Why does console.log of fs.readFile data not log a string?

Tags: node.js

I have the following code:

```
http = require("http");
fs = require("fs");

fs.readFile("file.txt", function(err, data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

The contents of file.txt is "Hello world", so I expected "Hello world" to be logged to the console. Instead, I got "Buffer" and then some hexadecimal numbers. Why is this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Node.js' fs.readFile() return a buffer instead of string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456864/why-does-node-js-fs-readfile-return-a-buffer-instead-of-string)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't pass an encoding type as part of the options for `fs.readFile()`, then it gives you a Buffer object, not a string as the data.  If you specify an encoding that works for a string like `'utf8',` then it gives you a string.

```
const fs = require("fs");

fs.readFile("file.txt", 'utf8', function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
      console.log(err);
  } else {
      console.log(typeof data);    // "string"
      console.log(data);
  }
});
```

So, basically the encoding is an optional parameter and if not passed, then you get a Buffer object as the data which you could extract a string from, but it's better to pass whatever encoding you are expecting from the data in the file.

Note: This is pretty clearly explained in [the doc for fs.readFile()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback).

P.S. Please declare your variables `fs` and `http` properly.